# svn: external failed directory error Can't obtain lock on non-directory 'directory'

Tags: svn

I have just loaded some old files and directories of an old project onto my PC from SVN to debug an issue.

I am getting the following when trying to update the working directory:

```
external failed directory error Can't obtain lock on non-directory 'directory'
```

I have tried `svn cleanup` as suggested by some posts but to no avail.

Anyone got any pointers as to how I might resolve this?

Comment: This is most likely due to the fact that you have sub-directories under that directory.

Answer (score 10):

It appears if I rename the existing directory and then get the code to a new directory the problem is solved.

Now I understand what those other posts meant.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue, could you please care to post the exact script changes so that I am sure what it means when you say "rename the existing directory and the get the code to new directory"

Comment: Same here... @kevins1966, could you share what you did?

Comment: to clarify; when you get the error message `Can't obtain lock on non-directory 'path\to\module_abc'`, then rename `module_abc` to `module_abc.bak`, and do a new svn update of the main project. You will get a new copy of module_abc.

Answer (score 6):

I cannot really tell what exactly was the problem, but for me the following workaround worked:
Remove (or rename if you changed files) the folder in question. Update -> The Folder will be recreated.

If necessary copy the files that you changed before.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
The problem was that the directory containing the resources already existed in the path in which it was pointing, it has to be deleted and the svn automatically creates it.

**Not works:**

Existing directories on destiny path:

version\

- ext1
- ext2

Path that will receive the external:

*version\\ext1*

Source path of the external:

*^/project1/resource/ext1*

**It works:**

Existing directories on destiny path:

version\

- ext2

Path that will receive the external:

*version\\ext1*

Source path of the external:

*^/project1/resource/ext1*

Answer (score 1):

This happens when in a directory external the .svn directory is deleted. This can happen for example when a script secretly deletes the local directory and replaces it by an exact copy without the ".svn" directory.

So if you delete this look-alike/doppelganger and restore the original from repo evertyhing is OK.

If you are known to ClearCase this effect is called an "eclipse".

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by not creating the directory which the external references before I perform SVN Update.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem after updating a working directory with svn:externals references. The solution was to change the order of the svn:externals so that the parent directory is fetched first.

This order caused the error:

```
 CoreLab\Src
 Corelab
```

The solution was to change the order to:

```
 Corelab
 CoreLab\Src
```

Maybe this will help other people who have the same problem.